# Create stored procedure to add with auto increment as its primary field?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert Data into my Sql-Server database though C#. I'm Calling a stored procedure and then would like it to add. I'm not sure what changes to make, but ultimately i would like it done in the stored procedure.

My Stored procedure now:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertTagProcdure]
       @TagID int, 
       @Value nvarchar(200), 
       @TagCount nvarchar(200) 
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Tag
                WHERE @TagID = @TagID)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
        Tag 
        (TagID,Value,TagCount) 
        VALUES 
        (@TagID,@Value,@TagCount)
END
```

And my C# Code:

```
int TagID = int.Parse(txtTagID.Text); //This should fall away so auto increment.
            String Value = txtValue.Text;
            int TagCount = int.Parse(txtCount.Text); 

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnectionString))
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = "InsertTagProcdure";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TagID", TagID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TagCount", TagCount);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

The Table Create i used: //Cant change this its what the boss gave me.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tag](
    [TagID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [TagCount] [varchar](200) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Tag] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TagID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: If you turn on auto incrementation on your primary key in SQL Server you won't need to pass the TagID, it will automatically increment and assign it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you would just make TagID an identity field by changing the table definition. If you can't do that, next best would be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertTagProcdure]
       @Value nvarchar(200), 
       @TagCount nvarchar(200) 
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DECLARE @TagID int;
        SELECT @TagID = coalesce((select max(TagID) + 1 from Tag), 1)
    COMMIT      
    INSERT INTO 
        Tag 
        (TagID,Value,TagCount) 
        VALUES 
        (@TagID,@Value,@TagCount)
END
```

The transaction ensures that you don't end up with unique TagIDs and the coalesce handles the special case where the table is empty and gives an initial value of 1.

**EDIT:**

Based on the change to your original question, the table already has an identity column so your stored procedure should be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertTagProcdure]
       @Value nvarchar(200), 
       @TagCount nvarchar(200) 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Tag (Value,TagCount) VALUES (@Value,@TagCount)
END
```

and your C# code should be

int TagID = int.Parse(txtTagID.Text); //This should fall away so auto increment.
            String Value = txtValue.Text;
            int TagCount = int.Parse(txtCount.Text);

```
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "InsertTagProcdure";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TagCount", TagCount);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: I got this exception :Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Tag' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: @Pomster - my answer was an either / or option. If you've set the column to be an identity one, your problem is solved - just delete the bits of your original stored proc that deal with the TagID. The SP I've given here was in case you didn't have access to change the table schema. HTH

Comment: I'm Not allowed to change any thing on the database set up, so i tyred you code and got that error. Im not sure what els you telling me to do?

Comment: Could you explain in easy words what i should do? what are my options? i cant change anything on how the database was created.

Comment: @Pomster I just did! Read from the word "EDIT" - you've got a little change to your stored procedure and a little change to your c# code. Copy and paste what I've put there and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the tag table up so that it uses the identity property. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(v=sql.80).aspx.

Then you can drop TagId from the procedure, the insert statement in the procedure and the c# code.

It then becomes something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertTagProcdure]
       @Value nvarchar(200), 
       @TagCount nvarchar(200) 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
        Tag 
        (Value,TagCount) 
        VALUES 
        (@Value,@TagCount)
END
```

C# Code:

```
            String Value = txtValue.Text;
            int TagCount = int.Parse(txtCount.Text); 

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnectionString))
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = "InsertTagProcdure";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TagCount", TagCount);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

the statement WHERE @TagID = @TagID will always be true, because your comparing the same values.
I *think* your looking for this (assuming TagID is your AUTO-ID field);

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertTagProcdure] 
       @TagID int,  
       @Value nvarchar(200),  
       @TagCount nvarchar(200)  
AS 
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TagID FROM Tag WHERE TagID = @TagID) 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO  
        Tag  
        (Value,TagCount)  
        VALUES  
        (@Value,@TagCount) 
  SET @TagID = @@IDENTITY
END 
ELSE
BEGIN
  UPDATE Tag
    SET Value=@Value,
    TagCount=@TagCount
  WHERE TagID = @TagID
END
RETURN @TagID
END
```

Comment: Could not Create stored procedure error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InsertTagTest, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

Comment: I forgot a BEGIN in the start of the stored proc - adjusted, but I suggest you read Dave's comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn on 'Identity specification' in SQL Server on the appropriate column. Go to table design mode, select the column and in the bottom properties screen there is a property called 'Identity specification'.

After this, you can omit the TagId in your stored procedure. Sql Server will automatically assign an id to a new record.

If you want to know what that newly inserted id is (which I assume is your next question), you can use the function SCOPE_IDENTITY() in your stored procedure, which returns the id of the newly inserted record.