# Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied, when parameter is auto-generated

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008, autogeneratecolumn

I'm trying to insert data in my db. this is the code im using

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.UsersInsert", cnn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserFirstName", FirstName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserMiddleName", MiddleName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserLastName", LastName.Text);
```

etc...

It is giving me error

> Procedure or function 'UsersInsert' expects parameter '@UserID', which
>   was not supplied.

on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); line.

Here, My UserID is auto-generated in my Database. How do I resolve this?

Stored Procedure

```
 @UserID INT OUTPUT,   
 @UserFirstName VARCHAR (50),  
 @UserMiddleName VARCHAR (50),  
 @UserLastName VARCHAR (50), etc... 

AS  
SET NOCOUNT ON  
DECLARE @ReturnValue int  
BEGIN  

 SELECT @ReturnValue = 0  

 INSERT [Users]  
 ( 
            [UserFirstName]
           ,[UserMiddleName]
           ,[UserLastName] etc... 
 values (

         @UserFirstName,  
                 @UserMiddleName,  
                 @UserLastName,  etc.. )
IF (@@Error <> 0) GOTO ERROR_HANDLER

 GOTO OnExit  
END
```

Comment: i think you shouldn't add as a parameter

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10614457/2501279

Answer (score 1):

You should make it an `ParameterDirection.Output`

```
SqlParameter userIdParam = new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int);
userIdParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(userIdParam);
```

This way you don't have to supply a value

Comment: I tried what you said, now its giving me, "Error converting data type nvarchar to int." this error.

Comment: This means that your storedprocedure had defined the UserID parameter as nvarchar. Or you should change the storedprocedure to int, or you should change the SqlParameter dbType to nvarchar.

Comment: Storedprocedure has defined UserID as int. and I converting the parameter to nvarchar, then it gives me error "Error converting data type int to nvarchar.". This is getting very frustrating.

Comment: Where do you assign the @UserID in the storedproc? It will be DBNull i guess. A DBNull cannot be converted to an int. Try setting at the end of the StoredProc `SET @UserID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: Tried. No avail. :(
BTW Anyone knows how to edit a function in MS SQL server?

Comment: Nothing in your current code gives any clue why it would be returning that error. I suggest you post a new question with _all_ of the stored proc code and this new error, referring to this question. To edit a stored proc in SQL Server, you need to script it out as modify, make changes then run the script to change it. There are many explanations if you google it. Like this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/modify-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work, change the sql to accept the parameters

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.UsersInsert @UserID out, @UserFirstName, @UserMiddleName, @UserLastName", cnn);
```

Then change the parameters as follows

```
var id = new SqlParameter("UserID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
id.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(id);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserFirstName", FirstName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserMiddleName", MiddleName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserLastName", LastName.Text);
```