# Auto increment value on adding a row using C# WPF and SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I'm working with C# WPF in Visual Studio Express 2012.  I've created a local service-based database (`.mdf` database).

I've created a table with

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Scenes] (
         [id]              INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
         [Planning_period] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
         [Scene_name]      NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
    );
```

I want to be able to add a new row but the following code doesn't work because I'm leaving id as null.  How do I get it to increment automatically when I add data?

```
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::WaterfowlModel.Properties.Settings.Default.WAMConnectionString);
    try
    {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO Scenes (Planning_period, Scene_name) Values ('" + working_plan + "','" + Create_plan_txt.Text +"')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
    finally
    {
        cn.Close();
    }
```

Thanks!

EDIT

I've attempted this with a stored procedure as well and received the same error.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Add_Scene]
    @param1 nvarchar(50),
    @param2 nvarchar(50)
AS
    INSERT INTO Scenes(Planning_period, Scene_name)
    VALUES(@param1, @param2)
```

and code:

```
        string sql = "Add_Scene";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
        SqlParameter planname = new SqlParameter("@param1", working_plan);
        SqlParameter scenename = new SqlParameter("@param2", Create_plan_txt.Text);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(planname);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(scenename);
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What makes you think its not working ?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but speaks to a convention you're using. Do NOT create SQL statements through concatenation! Use parameters instead. (example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) Otherwise, you're leaving yourself open to SQL injection.

Comment: You are correct Bob.  I do need to change these to parameters.

Comment: Have you got any error message?

Comment: What makes you think it is not incrementing?  That is want an identity does.

Comment: I receive the error message Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table Scenes; column does not allow nulls.  INSERT fails.

Comment: Remove the `catch (Exception ex)` and tell us the **full error message** including stack trace.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'D:\SOURCE CODE\WATERFOWLMODEL\WATERFOWLMODEL\BIN\DEBUG\WAM.MDF.dbo.Scenes'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The statement has been terminated.

Call Stac> WaterfowlModel.exe!WaterfowlModel.MainWindow.create_new_scene_button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) Line 151 + 0xb bytes C#

Comment: So this really isn't an answer but instead of clicking the Start button at the top I rebuilt and then clicked start... and it all started working using the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed instructions found [Create stored procedure to add with auto increment as its primary field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614351/create-stored-procedure-to-add-with-auto-increment-as-its-primary-field)

One thing I had to do was rebuild the solution before Starting the application.  Before I rebuilt it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First you should be carefull using that code, you should user parameters for the sqlCommand, and not made a concatenation...

Second to work with the database you should see how to make the call, not using the sql Insert statement, but calling a stored procedure, that insert the record on the table, and holds the Insert statement.

So resuming, if you see how to do what I answered you, you'll see that once you have the stored procedure working fine, you will be able to made the auto increment without worries ;).

And you win in all, because you code will be more robust, secure and reliable.

Greetings.

Comment: Great suggestions! But how this can help OP to solve its problem?

Comment: After you execute the Insert Stored Procedure, you can select your data again, and the values are incremented, because when you made the Insert the field id is Identity(1, 1)...

Comment: Agree with @HamletHakobyan. This would be better as a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the change you have made, you just need to return the ID in the Stored Procedure after the Insert, you have cupple of ways to do that, but be carefull...

If you do not have lots of traffic in your database you can use just this, is more faster:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Add_Scene]
    @param1 nvarchar(50),
    @param2 nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Scenes(Planning_period, Scene_name)
    VALUES(@param1, @param2)

    RETURN @@IDENTITY
END
```

This is a standard for this type of Stored Procedure, as you can see here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx. However this function may not return the correct value, if you are working in a environment with lots of database traffic, it just return the ID of the last Insert operation, if there is concurrency, you may have problems, so check for other options, that may be slower in execution but more reliable.

The main point is to return from the database the ID auto incremented, after the insert, so you can read the value of the insert you made.

Hope that this helps you.

Greetings.