# Creating a compiled query linq and performance issues with regular LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently have a query which looks like following:

```
 using (var ctx = new myEntities())
 {
    ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    ctx.Database.CommandTimeout = 200;
    competitors = DBRetry.Do(() => ctx.SearchedUsers.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.InQueue == true).OrderBy(x => x.LastUpdatedAt).Take(2000).ToList(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

 }
```

Since often the table "SearchedUsers" is used by other users/applications, I commonly get slowdowns/deadlocks when doing a query against this database.

I've done a little bit of research to speed up this process by turning off lazy loading, using AsNoTracking() trick with the quer and increasing the command timeout when performing the query against the DB, however the deadlocks occur still sometimes...

So my questions here are:

1. How would I turn this query into a compiled one
2. How much of a performance could I expect when performing a compiled query vs the regular one?

Can someone help me out to implement the compiled query solution one ?

Comment: Do you have an index on LastUpdatedAt? As you are ordening on that field it might speed up the query.

Comment: @johey yes there's an index on that one as well :)

Comment: What database are you using?  The locking is at the database and not in the Net Library when multi-users are connecting to the database.  SQL Server do lock while oledb (back-end for access and excel) does not lock (even when files are in shared mode).

Comment: @jdweng MSSQL 2016 version is the database that is used

Comment: MSSQL does lock but you have to make sure any Primary key gets allocated uniquely.  Duplicate Primary key can cause issues.  When you have multi-users you want to use a stored procedure to assign the primary.See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614351/create-stored-procedure-to-add-with-auto-increment-as-its-primary-field.Also SQL Server is multi-task operating database and does split queries into into more than one process.  So you have to wait until all process finish which can take a long time.De-Fragmenting can help.You also can be delayed in database is using more than one server.

Comment: Additional comments : 1) You c# code should not have any locking.  Let the server handle the conflicts 2) If you have a cluster of server make sure each cluster is assigning different ranges of primary keys 3) To determine if the server or c# is causing a performance issue use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to get the response times from the server.

Comment: I think you may speed up things here: you load everything into the memory by calling `.ToList()`, so you can try to avoid that and use iterator?

Answer (score 1):

Create your query as a view in the database.  Set a NOLOCK hint on the query or ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED.  Then set your model object to the view as a table.

Compiling the query would help with performance, but it's not going to help you with the locking of records.

Also, why are you using the CommandTimeout of 200 milliseconds? What happens if you tweak that?